# How do I make an ADO connection timeout sooner if the server doesnt exist?

Tags: sql, vb6, timeout, database-connection, ado

I have been tasked w/ supporting an old VB6 app. (yay me) I am having trouble with the ADO connection timeout property.  The method below works fine if the server exists, but if the server does not exist or network connections havent started up for the machine it will take a full 30 seconds to timeout even with the intTimeout set to 1.

Is there a way for ADO to fail to connect sooner?
Is this even possible?
Thanks!

```
Public Sub GetConnectionObject(ByRef oCn As ADODB.Connection, strServer As String,     strInitialCatalog As String, Optional intTimeout = 10)

    Dim strConnectionString As String
    strConnectionString = "Data Source=[SERVER];Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=ScanReq1;Password=ScanR3Q;Initial Catalog=[INITIALCATALOG];ConnectionTimeout=" & intTimeout & ";"
    strConnectionString = Replace(strConnectionString, "[SERVER]", strServer)
    strConnectionString = Replace(strConnectionString, "[INITIALCATALOG]", strInitialCatalog)

    Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
    oCn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    oCn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    oCn.CommandTimeout = intTimeout
    oCn.ConnectionTimeout = intTimeout

    oCn.Open

End Sub
```

Comment: It must be name resolution problem. You can speed it up on TCP by using DNS only (no broadcasts + timeout) and directly using IP address for [SERVER]. In your place I wouldn't bother too much with this "performance" issue.

Answer (score 5):

The ConnectionTimeout kicks in after the TCP connection is made.  If the server can't be found, this value is controlled by the Windows TCP subsystem.

If this really is an issue for you, I'd try to ping the box first (there are plenty examples of pinging via VB6 on the net).

Answer (score 1):

I've also hit this one.  An alternative to setting `ConnectionTimeout` could be to make the `Open` call asynchronous, then handle the timeout in your own code.  Quick and dirty example below (**note: this is in VBA, but should be easily ported to VB6**):

```vb
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim time As Single, timeOut As Single
conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string here"
conn.Open Options:=adAsyncConnect  ' value is 16
timeOut = 5
time = Timer()
Do Until Timer() - time > timeOut Or conn.State = adStateOpen
    DoEvents
Loop
If conn.State <> adStateOpen Then    'value is 1
    'timed out
Else
    'successful
End If
```

To do it "properly", there is a `ConnectionComplete` event which you could handle.

Comment: This is an interesting angle that I was able to implement and it seems to work.  Note that `conn2` should be renamed `conn`.  If this code is behind a button, the DoEvents will allow the button to be clicked multiple times which will start multiple checks.  My solution to that was to set the Hourglass at the top of this code and clear it at the end.  Then add `If Screen.Mousepointer=0 Then` above the line turning on the Hourglass.